# Why are all sites blocked when I use declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I need to block some http requests with new manifest v3. I try to use declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules, but any rule blocks all requests, and I can't open any site. For example https://developer.chrome.com.

Code example:

```
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
   removeRuleIds: [232],
   addRules: [{
     id: 232,
     "condition": { "urlFilter": "analytics", "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"] },
     action: {
       "type": "block",

     },
   }]
});
```

Can somebody help me?)

Comment: This rule is ok, which means there's an older rule still applied. It may be in the static rules in manifest.json's declarative_net_request key or in the dynamic rules, which you can remove by using getDynamicRules and updateDynamicRules with removeRuleIds.

Comment: thank you, I removed dynamic rules and it start working